# Determine process uptime

Tags: windows, uptime, task-manager

Is there a way to determine the 'uptime' of a process in Windows. Disappointed to find that it is not one of the attributes available when using the Task Manager.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can see this with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). In the taskbar menu select `View` and check `Show Process Tree` and the `Show Lower Pane` options. Right click on any column and `Select Columns`, now click on the `Process Performance` tab and check the `Start Time` box.

**Community Update:**

As mentioned in the comments, in more recent versions of the tool (currently as of 2019), the information has been relocated into the image tab of the property sheets regarding each process-tree item (Just `double-click` the process name, no other steps are required).

[image]

Comment: Hey TiZon. This looks a really useful tool. Thanks

Comment: Or you can right click, Properties and on Threads tab, there is start time.

Comment: In the link, Download section, "Run now from Sysinternals Live", when running, the `process tree` is not clickable in the view. I have windows 7 enterprise, so maybe it is blocked by my firewall.

Comment: @Betlista, there is no threads tab in Properties

Comment: This answer is outdated. For Process Explorer v16.26, right click the process -> Properties -> Threads tab -> start time is listed below. No need to check `Show Process Tree` or `Show Lower Pane`. The `Performance` tab does not list start time any more. The lower pane isn't used to find the start time.

Answer (score 39):

This can be done using Powershell.

Run it as admin and then execute

Get-Process | select name, starttime

You will get a list of all running processes and their start times

Referenced from:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/18/powertip-use-powershell-to-easily-see-process-start-time.aspx

Comment: I see values for most of the services but the one I want (w3wp) doesn't have a start time listed.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a server where you cannot install any external tool, you still can :

1. Open the task manager
2. Click on the process tab
3. Locate your process
4. Right click on it
5. Select the Properties option

You can see a "creation date" right there, which should be the creation date of your process. With a simple substraction you can deduce the uptime.

Comment: This only works on Windows 8. If you are still on Windows 7, the Properties option shows properties of the running executable file, not of the process.

Comment: Win 8.1 also shows executable file properties

Comment: Windows 11: this displays the file creation time, not the process creation time.

Answer (score 3):

In **CMD** you can use standard Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line (**WMIC**) utility to get the process start time:

```
wmic process where Name="<process name>" get CreationDate
```

or

```
wmic process where ProcessID="<PID>" get CreationDate
```

You'll get a datetime like this: `20201021010512.852810+180`.
Format: `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.ssssss+MMM(UTC offset)`

If you want a more readable representation you'd need to prep it with a script. Here I have written a little batch script for the purpose:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

IF [%1]==[] (
    ECHO Prints process creation date in ISO format. 
    ECHO:
    ECHO USAGE: %~n0 ^<PID or Process name^>
    EXIT /B 1
)

IF [%~x1]==[.exe] (SET type=Name) ELSE (SET type=ProcessID)

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a IN ('wmic process where %type%^="%~1" get CreationDate /value') DO (
    IF [%%a]==[CreationDate] SET proc_cd=%%b
)

IF DEFINED proc_cd (
    ECHO %proc_cd:~0,4%-%proc_cd:~4,2%-%proc_cd:~6,2%T%proc_cd:~8,2%:%proc_cd:~10,2%:%proc_cd:~12,2%
)
```

Feed it with a PID or a process name ending with .exe and it will output when the process was started. **Caveat**: If there are many processes with the same name it would output the time only for the last one started.

Answer (score 1):

Open *Task Manager* and right-click on the process. Choose *Properties* in the menu and look at the field *Accessed* in the first tab. Unless multiple instances have been started this will give you the start time of the process.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try procxp http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Answer (score 0):

With the PID from Task Manager, you can use the following Powershell command with the implied -End (Get-Date):

```
New-Timespan -Start (Get-Process -Id PID).StartTime
```